# Não lê o backend na View - Ionic + AngularJs:

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Estou conseguindo ler o meu backend, mas não consigo mostrar os dados em minha view, o que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Em meu controller fiz o seguinte, sendo que já de inicio pedi pra ler meu backend:

```
.controller("restaurantesCtrl", function($scope,$state,$ionicScrollDelegate,$http,$stateParams,$timeout,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$ionicPopover,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$ionicHistory,ionicMaterialInk,ionicMaterialMotion){


$scope.itens = [];

$http.get('http://nhac.esy.es/lista_restaurantes.php')
.success(function(itens){
    $scope.itens = itens;
    console.log("leu");  
    console.log($scope.itens = itens);
})
.error(function(erro){
   console.log(erro);
    console.log("não leu")
});
```

Na minha view fiz o seguinte:

```
    <ion-view view-title="Restaurantes" hide-nav-bar="false" >
    <ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll  id="page-restaurantes" class="has-header page-restaurantes" >

        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Role para atualizar..."  on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
        <ion-list class="card list">
            <div class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter promoess" />
            </div>
        </ion-list>

        <div class="list" ng-repeat="r in itens track by $index" >

        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/nhaac/restaurante_singles/">
              <img src="/img/logo_restaurante.jpg">

              <h2>{{r.fornecedores_fantasia}}  </h2>

              <h3>{{r.fornecedores_bairro}} </h3>  


                   <i><rating ng-model="contato.stars" max="rating.max"></rating></i>

              <p>Aqui a descrição do restaurante. </p>                  
              <button class="button button-block button-royal">
                  VER AS PROMOÇÕES
              </button>
            </a>

        </div>


        <ion-list class="list">
            <div class="item" ng-if="results.length == 0" >
                <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado...</p>
            </div>
        </ion-list>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Lembrando que estou buscando os resultados de http://nhac.esy.es/lista_restaurantes.php

No meu log, lista tudo. Mas na view não lista nada...

Comment: onde no seu html vc está listando? Só achei o ng-repeat do "pessoas". No sucess do seu get vc joga o resultado na variavel "retorno", por que então vc setou $scope.itens = []; ?

Comment: Corrigi estas questões, inclusive aqui na pergunta. É que tinha tentado em service e esqueci de mudar as views e o controller, mesmo assim, continua o erro.

Comment: Alterei meu controller para:     $scope.itens = [];

    $http.get('http://nhac.esy.es/lista_restaurantes.php')
    .success(function(retorno){
        $scope.itens = retorno;
        console.log("leu");  
        console.log($scope.itens = retorno);
    })
    .error(function(erro){
       console.log(erro);
        console.log("não leu")
    });

Comment: Vi no seu json que gera no "http://nhac.esy.es/lista_restaurantes.php" a estrutura está dentro de uma chave "{"user":[", veja no seu console.log como vem, não consegui simular aqui mas acredito que se vc fizer $scope.itens = itens.user; já resolve. Veja no seu console.log

Comment: Sim, vem este  "{"user":[", e no console ele é listado também. Não entendi onde colocar o $scope.itens = itens.user;

Comment: Vc está trabalhando com um array de objetos, os objetos que vc quer fazer loop estão dentro desse "user". No sucess do seu get ao inves de usar "$scope.itens = itens;" coloca "$scope.itens = itens.user;"

Answer (score 0):

Alterei meu controller para:

```
    $scope.itens = [];

$http.get('http://nhac.esy.es/lista_restaurantes.php')
.success(function(retorno){
    $scope.itens = retorno;
    console.log("leu");  
    console.log($scope.itens = retorno);
})
.error(function(erro){
   console.log(erro);
    console.log("não leu")
});
```

E a View, no trecho:

```
           <div class="list" ng-controller="restaurantesCtrl" ng-repeat="r in itens" >

        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#/nhaac/restaurante_singles/">
              <img src="/img/logo_restaurante.jpg">

              <h2>{{r.fornecedores_fantasia}}  </h2>

              <h3>{{r.fornecedores_bairro}} </h3>  


                   <i><rating ng-model="contato.stars" max="rating.max"></rating></i>

              <p>Aqui a descrição do restaurante. </p>                  
              <button class="button button-block button-royal">
                  VER AS PROMOÇÕES
              </button>
            </a>

        </div>
```

Agora a mensagem é:

ionic.bundle.js:26771 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: r in itens, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=r%20in%20itens&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
    at ionic.bundle.js:13415
    at ngRepeatAction (ionic.bundle.js:42146)
    at $watchCollectionAction (ionic.bundle.js:30081)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30480)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24801)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:24999)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24940)

Comment: Se coloco ng-repeat="r in itens track by $index" não dá o erro, mas não apresentam meus dados...

Comment: Pessoal, obrigado! Estou voltando só pra agradecer. Valeu mesmo! :))